# onCLickListener Javascript not working with this dojo code in IBM worklight

Tags: javascript, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM Worklight 6.0 to make a hybrid mobile app now what i am trying to do is invoke some javascript function on click of the list items, for now i have included simple alert here , though in my app it is a function 
my code fragment is as below

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="lessonIndexView"
data-dojo-props="selected:true">
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Accordion">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props='label:"PaneId1"'>
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
            data-dojo-props="label:'Item'" moveTo="codeView" id="l1" transition="slide"></div>
    </div>
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props='label:"PaneId2"' >
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" 
            data-dojo-props="label:'Item'" moveTo="codeView" transition="slide"></div>
    </div>          
</div>
```

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="codeView"
data-dojo-props="selected:false">
Code View
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRect">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
        data-dojo-props="label:'Item'" moveTo="lessonIndexView" transition="slide"></div>
    </div>
```

Now what i am trying is something like

```
$("#l1").click(function(){alert("some text");});
```

now this alert is nowhere being called in my app , can anyone tell me where i did the mistake , i know it must be some silly one because i think i have used it before, i dont know perfectly though....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Codesnippet form the Modern Dojo-Tutorial:

```
<script>
   require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/parser", "dojo/ready", "dijit/registry",   "dijit/form/Button"],
  function(dom, on, parser, ready, registry){
  var myClick = function(evt){
  console.log("I was clicked");
};

ready(function(){
  parser.parse();

  on(dom.byId("button1"), "click", myClick);
  on(registry.byId("button2"), "click", myClick);
});
});
</script>
<body>
 <div>
<button id="button1" type="button">Button1</button>
<button id="button2" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">Button2</button>
<button id="button3" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">
  <div>Button4</div>
  <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="click">
    console.log("I was clicked");
  </script>
</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Check this one too: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/modern_dojo/
If you scroll down, you'l get to the Events.

Reagrds

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the moveTo with onClick function.

And I assume you are linking the js to the page.

Comment: no i wanted a handler function as well as the moveTo attribute to navigate around. and yes i linked the js, no problems there....